# React ES6 Class transitionTo Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Inside Class

```
constructor(props, context) {
super(props, context);

someFn = () = {    
    this.context.router.transitionTo('google.com');
}
```

at the bottom of component

```
MyComponent.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

I keep getting the error *Warning: Failed Context Types: Required context `router` was not specified in `Homepage`.*

When I click on the button to navigate I get the following additional error *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property `transitionTo` of undefined*

I've even tried adding the following in the constructor but to no avail

```
this.context = context
```

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of applications do not need to use context. (ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Below should help you =>

```
import {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class MyComponent extends Component {

  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
  };

  onFormSubmit() {
    this.context.router.push('/home');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)}>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question in react-router github repo and got the answer
https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/2107

the gist: `history` is replacement for old `router`

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  static contextTypes= {
    history: React.PropTypes.object,
    location: React.PropTypes.object
  }
  render() {
      console.log(this.context.history, this.context.location)
      return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried below and worked correctly.
My `react-router` is `1.0.0-rc3`.

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    static contextTypes = {
        history: React.PropTypes.object
    }
    routeHandler() {
        this.context.history.pushState(null, '/test');
    }
    render() {
        return <button onClick={this.routeHandler.bind(this)} />;
    }
}
```